# Two random blocks displaying different fields from the same node

Tags: 7, views, blocks

I have a content type with field_1 and field_2. I want to have two blocks displaying different fields from a **one** random node. I can easily create two random blocks via views module, but they wil not be synchronized. Any ideas?

Comment: Why would you even need that? Can't you make it one block, and then style it to look like two, for example?

Comment: I understand that there are many ways to achieve similar behaviour. But I'm curious :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Define helper function like `_random_node_id()` which stores generated id in the static variable.
2. Use this function as an argument in the view.

This function will return a random node id, but called twice on the same page it would return the same id (because it is static).

Comment: Won't work if one of the blocks will get loaded from cache from some reason.

Comment: Assuming CACHE_PER_PAGE it should be ok. Tricky case => tricky solution J