# 2 views blocks on 1 page - no duplicate results

Tags: views

I have 2 views blocks with the same filter criteria. Both are displayed in different regions on 1 page. But they should not display the same results.

Is there a solution for that?

**Note**: The views have the same data. But they are sorted randomly.

Comment: if they have present the same data with the same filter criteria, they will always show the same results

Comment: Similar (if not duplicate): http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/163365

Answer (score 0):

There are a few solutions:

1. You can use [Panels](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels) module to build your page. Using this module you can insert a block in multiple times.
2. You can use this code into different regions to display the view

   ```
   <?php print views_embed_view("VIEW_NAME","MACHINE_NAME","ARGUMENTS");
   ```

   The [views_embed_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/views.module/function/views_embed_view/7) displays the view.
3. You can also load the block itself despite of what entity has generated it's content by the following code

   ```
   <?php
     $block = module_invoke('module_name', 'block_view', 'block_delta');
     print render($block['content']);
   ?>
   ```

The [How to insert a block into a node or template in Drupal 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4731420/how-to-insert-a-block-into-a-node-or-template-in-drupal-7) gives you more details about the arguments of above code.

Comment: I'm on holidays right now and will give it a try when I'm back.

Answer (score 0):

## Assumption

I'm assuming that the total number of rows returned by the view is at least twice the number of rows you display in each view. If not there is no correct solution possible to your question. E.g.: if you display 5 rows in each block, you must have at least 10 results (total number) ...

## Approach

Sort the view in the 1st block on "some column", say ascending (alternative: descending). And sort the view in the 2nd block on "the same column", say descending (alternative: ascending). In case you don't want the selected column to be shown in your block, just "hide it from the display".

## Pick a column

Probably a good (best?) fit could be the column you already used for that "random sorting" (you didn't mention yet HOW you implemented that sorting ...). If you don't have such column yet, check if any of the existing fields available in your view can be used for it (such as a node Id or something similar).